# Gemified Plugins Architecture\Design Patterns in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, plugins

In framework-like ruby projects, how is it possible to package a plugins as gems and then use\unuse them inside the project, Most popular living example is Rails, but I seeking the abstracted concepts\practices\design patterns that can aid in building such project architecture.

Rails sourcecode is TOO big to navigate without a map.

Research Log:
- In Rails, Railities are assumed to be a good place to start exploring how plugin architecture is implemented.
- In Ruby 1.8, there was a C extension called mixology that provides mix\unmix constructs.
- In Ruby 1.9.*, It is believed that Rails used alias_method_chain 
- In Ruby 2.0 prepend keyword is meant to be useful in solving such problem (I assume!)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best introductions into topic I have seen so far was a Railscast where Ryan extracts some piece of his app into a gem:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/301-extracting-a-ruby-gem

Generally there are few rules to follow to make Your code easy extractable:

- Extract common logic to modules or even better separate service objects
- Following [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles will make Your units lean and isolated as much as possible
- ALWAYS namespace Your concerns, service objects, libraries etc
- Test those units completely isolated, don't rely on details like database
- (Controversial) Do dependency injections, You won't regret this when testing and simply when designing APIs between Your objects
- Avoid using Rails helpers as much as possible if You intend Your code to be reusable outside a Rails context

I hope these suggestions will put You on Your own Rails :)